# Chartjs unexpected behaviour of updates given double Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

The unexpected behaviour is due to how the chart (ChartJs) is updating due to the values of the input<'input-left'> and input<'input-right'> which is done by the 'UpdateSlider' function. When I move the input<'input-right'> to the left, the chart updates correctly moving to the left. Instead, when I move the input<'input-left'> to the right the behaviour is the same as the input<'input-right'>. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

```js
var inputLeft = document.getElementById("input-left");
var inputRight = document.getElementById("input-right");

var thumbLeft = document.querySelector(".slider > .thumb.left");
var thumbRight = document.querySelector(".slider > .thumb.right");
var range = document.querySelector(".slider > .range");

function setLeftValue() {
    var _this = inputLeft,
      min = parseInt(_this.min),
      max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.min(parseInt(_this.value), parseInt(inputRight.value) - 1);

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbLeft.style.left = percent + "%";
    range.style.left = percent + "%";
}

setLeftValue();

function setRightValue() {
    var _this = inputRight,
      min = parseInt(_this.min),
      max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.max(parseInt(_this.value), parseInt(inputLeft.value) + 1);

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbRight.style.right = (100 - percent) + "%";
    range.style.right = (100 - percent) + "%";
}

setRightValue();

inputLeft.addEventListener("input", setLeftValue);
inputRight.addEventListener("input", setRightValue);

inputLeft.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    thumbLeft.classList.add("hover");
});
inputLeft.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    thumbLeft.classList.remove("hover");
});
inputLeft.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    thumbLeft.classList.add("active");
});
inputLeft.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    thumbLeft.classList.remove("active");
});

inputRight.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    thumbRight.classList.add("hover");
});
inputRight.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    thumbRight.classList.remove("hover");
});
inputRight.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    thumbRight.classList.add("active");
});
inputRight.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    thumbRight.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
.centre {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.slider>.track {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #c6aee7;
}

.slider>.range {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #6200ee;
}

.slider>.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #6200ee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(98, 0, 238, .1);
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
}

.slider>.thumb.left {
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-15px, -10px);
}

.slider>.thumb.right {
  right: 25%;
  transform: translate(15px, -10px);
}

.slider>.thumb.hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(98, 0, 238, .1);
}

.slider>.thumb.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px rgba(98, 0, 238, .2);
}

input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

        <canvas id="main-js-chart" height="100"></canvas>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            const tooltipLine = {
              id: 'tooltipLine',
              beforeDraw: function(chart) {
                  if (chart.tooltip._active && chart.tooltip._active.length) {

                      var activePoint = chart.tooltip._active[0],
                          ctx = chart.ctx,
                          y_axis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'],
                          x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
                          y = activePoint.tooltipPosition().y,
                          topY = y_axis.top,
                          bottomY = y_axis.bottom;

                      ctx.save();
                      ctx.beginPath();
                      ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);
                      ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
                      ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
                      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                      ctx.strokeStyle = activePoint._view.borderColor;
                      ctx.stroke();
                      ctx.restore();

                  }
              }
          }


          var ctx = document.getElementById("main-js-chart").getContext("2d");
          var data = {
          labels:   ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
             "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "January",  
              "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
             "July", "August", "September", "October", "November" 
            ],
          datasets: [{
              label: "Nyse",
              borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
              fill: false,
              pointStyle: 'dot',
              borderWidth: 1.5,
              pointRadius: (ctx) => {
                  const pointsLenght = ctx.chart.data.labels.length -1;
                  const pointsArray = [];
                  for (let i=0; i<=pointsLenght; i++) {
                  if (i == pointsLenght | i == 0) {
                      pointsArray.push(3.5);
                  }
                  else {
                      pointsArray.push(0);
                  }
                  }
                  return pointsArray;
              },
              data:  [-20, -59, 20, 77, 81, 46, -23, -60, -58, -25, 33 
                 -20, -59, 20, 77, 81, 46, -23, -60, -58, -25, 33, 67 
                ]
              },
              {
              label: "Nasdaq",
              borderColor: 'rgba(249, 153, 34, 225)',
              pointStyle: 'dot',
              fill: false,
              borderWidth: 1.5,
              pointRadius: (ctx) => {
                  const pointsLenght = ctx.chart.data.labels.length -1;
                  const pointsArray = [];
                  for (let i=0; i<=pointsLenght; i++) {
                  if (i == pointsLenght | i == 0) {
                      pointsArray.push(3.5);
                  }
                  else {
                      pointsArray.push(0);
                  }
                  }
                  return pointsArray;
              },
              data:  [-30, -56, 30, 67, 91, 56, -13, -50, -58, -5, 43, 
                 -30, -56, 30, 67, 91, 56, -13, -50, -58, -5, 43 
                ] 
              }
          ]
          };

                    var labels = data.labels;
          var options = {
          legend: {
              labels : {
                  usePointStyle: true
              }
          },
          hover: {
              intersect: false
          },
          tooltips: {
              mode: 'nearest',
              custom: function(tooltip) {
              if (!tooltip) return;
                  tooltip.displayColors = false;
              }
          },
          scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                      display:false
                  }
              }]
              }
          }

          var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "line",
          data: data,
          options: options,
          plugins: [tooltipLine]
          });
                    
                    
          function UpdateSlider(range) {
            var il = document.getElementById('input-left').value;
                var ir = document.getElementById('input-right').value;
            
            chart.data.labels = labels.slice(
                Math.ceil(labels.length * il / 100), Math.ceil(labels.length * ir / 100)
            );            
            chart.update();
            console.log(Math.ceil(labels.length * il / 100), Math.ceil(labels.length * ir / 100));
          };

        </script><br><br>

        <div class="centre">
            <div class="middle">
            <div class="multi-range-slider">
                <input oninput="UpdateSlider(this)" type="range" id="input-left" min="0" max="100" value="0">
                <input oninput="UpdateSlider(this)" type="range" id="input-right" min="0" max="100" value="100">
                <div class="slider">
                  <div class="track"></div>
                  <div class="range"></div>
                  <div class="thumb left"></div>
                  <div class="thumb right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var inputLeft = document.getElementById("input-left");
var inputRight = document.getElementById("input-right");

var thumbLeft = document.querySelector(".slider > .thumb.left");
var thumbRight = document.querySelector(".slider > .thumb.right");
var range = document.querySelector(".slider > .range");

function setLeftValue() {
    var _this = inputLeft,
      min = parseInt(_this.min),
      max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.min(parseInt(_this.value), parseInt(inputRight.value) - 1);

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbLeft.style.left = percent + "%";
    range.style.left = percent + "%";
}

setLeftValue();

function setRightValue() {
    var _this = inputRight,
      min = parseInt(_this.min),
      max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.max(parseInt(_this.value), parseInt(inputLeft.value) + 1);

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbRight.style.right = (100 - percent) + "%";
    range.style.right = (100 - percent) + "%";
}

setRightValue();

inputLeft.addEventListener("input", setLeftValue);
inputRight.addEventListener("input", setRightValue);

inputLeft.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    thumbLeft.classList.add("hover");
});
inputLeft.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    thumbLeft.classList.remove("hover");
});
inputLeft.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    thumbLeft.classList.add("active");
});
inputLeft.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    thumbLeft.classList.remove("active");
});

inputRight.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    thumbRight.classList.add("hover");
});
inputRight.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    thumbRight.classList.remove("hover");
});
inputRight.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    thumbRight.classList.add("active");
});
inputRight.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    thumbRight.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
.centre {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.slider>.track {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #c6aee7;
}

.slider>.range {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #6200ee;
}

.slider>.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #6200ee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(98, 0, 238, .1);
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
}

.slider>.thumb.left {
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-15px, -10px);
}

.slider>.thumb.right {
  right: 25%;
  transform: translate(15px, -10px);
}

.slider>.thumb.hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(98, 0, 238, .1);
}

.slider>.thumb.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px rgba(98, 0, 238, .2);
}

input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">


        <canvas id="main-js-chart" height="100"></canvas>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            const tooltipLine = {
              id: 'tooltipLine',
              beforeDraw: function(chart) {
                  if (chart.tooltip._active && chart.tooltip._active.length) {

                      var activePoint = chart.tooltip._active[0],
                          ctx = chart.ctx,
                          y_axis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'],
                          x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
                          y = activePoint.tooltipPosition().y,
                          topY = y_axis.top,
                          bottomY = y_axis.bottom;

                      ctx.save();
                      ctx.beginPath();
                      ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);
                      ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
                      ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
                      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                      ctx.strokeStyle = activePoint._view.borderColor;
                      ctx.stroke();
                      ctx.restore();

                  }
              }
          }
                    
          
          var data0 = [-30, -56, 30, 67, 91, 56, -13, -50, -58, -5, 43, 
                 -30, -56, 30, 67, 91, 56, -13, -50, -58, -5, 43];
          var data1 = [-20, -59, 20, 77, 81, 46, -23, -60, -58, -25, 33 
                 -20, -59, 20, 77, 81, 46, -23, -60, -58, -25, 33, 67];
          var labels =  ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
             "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "January",  
              "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
             "July", "August", "September", "October", "November"];
                 

          var ctx = document.getElementById("main-js-chart").getContext("2d");
          var data = {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [{
              label: "Nyse",
              borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
              fill: false,
              pointStyle: 'dot',
              borderWidth: 1.5,
              pointRadius: (ctx) => {
                  const pointsLenght = ctx.chart.data.labels.length -1;
                  const pointsArray = [];
                  for (let i=0; i<=pointsLenght; i++) {
                  if (i == pointsLenght | i == 0) {
                      pointsArray.push(3.5);
                  }
                  else {
                      pointsArray.push(0);
                  }
                  }
                  return pointsArray;
              },
              data: data0
              },
              {
              label: "Masdaq",
              borderColor: 'rgba(249, 153, 34, 225)',
              pointStyle: 'dot',
              fill: false,
              borderWidth: 1.5,
              pointRadius: (ctx) => {
                  const pointsLenght = ctx.chart.data.labels.length -1;
                  const pointsArray = [];
                  for (let i=0; i<=pointsLenght; i++) {
                  if (i == pointsLenght | i == 0) {
                      pointsArray.push(3.5);
                  }
                  else {
                      pointsArray.push(0);
                  }
                  }
                  return pointsArray;
              },
              data: data1
              }
          ]
          };

                    var labels = data.labels;
          var options = {
          legend: {
              labels : {
                  usePointStyle: true
              }
          },
          hover: {
              intersect: false
          },
          tooltips: {
              mode: 'nearest',
              custom: function(tooltip) {
              if (!tooltip) return;
                  tooltip.displayColors = false;
              }
          },
          scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                      display:false
                  }
              }]
              }
          }

          var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "line",
          data: data,
          options: options,
          plugins: [tooltipLine]
          });
                    
                    
          function UpdatesSlider(range) {
            var il = document.getElementById('input-left').value;
                var ir = document.getElementById('input-right').value;
            var abs_il = Math.ceil(data0.length * il / 100);
            var abs_ir = Math.ceil(data0.length * ir / 100);
            
            chart.data.labels = labels.slice(abs_il, abs_ir);      
            chart.data.datasets[0].data = data0.slice(abs_il, abs_ir); 
            chart.data.datasets[1].data = data1.slice(abs_il, abs_ir); 
            chart.update();
            console.log(abs_il, abs_ir);
          };

        </script><br><br>

        <div class="centre">
            <div class="middle">
            <div class="multi-range-slider">
                <input oninput="UpdatesSlider(this)" type="range" id="input-left" min="0" max="100" value="0">
                <input oninput="UpdatesSlider(this)" type="range" id="input-right" min="0" max="100" value="100">
                <div class="slider">
                  <div class="track"></div>
                  <div class="range"></div>
                  <div class="thumb left"></div>
                  <div class="thumb right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```